# Find the diagonal matrix A that satisfies the equation

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices

Find the diagonal matrix $A$ that that satisfies the equation:

$$A^{-3}=\pmatrix{-27&0&0\cr0&8&0\cr0&0&-1}$$

Attempted solution:

my intuition tells me that the inverse of the inverse of this the matrix will be the matrix $A$. But the inverse of the inverse is of course the original matrix.

Is that correct?

Cheers

Comment: The arithmetic of diagonal matrices is very straightforward; if you think about it, you should be able to write down $A^3$ without any work, and then $A$ itself.

Comment: so since $$(A^{-3})^{-1}=A^{3}$$ i just find the inverse of the given matrix and then find the cube root of all diagonals like so?

Comment: Yes, but what *is* $(A^{-3})^{-1}$? You can calculate it explicitly with almost no work. And yes, then you’ll be looking for the cube roots of the diagonal entries.

Comment: $$A^{3}=\pmatrix{-1/27&0&0\cr0&1/8&0\cr0&0&-1/1&\cr}$$ and then simply find the cube root of the matrix?

Comment: therefore $$3sqrt[A^{3}]=\pmatrix{-1/3&0&0\cr0&1/2&0\cr0&0&1&\cr}$$ 3sqrt as in the cube root.... Is this correct?

Comment: Almost: you’ve got the wrong sign for the bottom entry on the diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $A$ is a diagonal matrix, it can be written as

$$A=\pmatrix{a_{11}&0&0\cr0&a_{22}&0\cr0&0&a_{33}}$$

By definition, $A^{-3} = (A^{-1})^3$, hence we first see, by directly checking left and right multiplication of following matrix on $A$ yields the identity matrix $I$, that

$$A^{-1}=\pmatrix{a_{11}^{-1}&0&0\cr0&a_{22}^{-1}&0\cr0&0&a_{33}^{-1}}$$

and thus, by directly raising the power three to the above matrix, that

$$A^{-3}=\pmatrix{a_{11}^{-3}&0&0\cr0&a_{22}^{-3}&0\cr0&0&a_{33}^{-3}}$$

and we have, by the setting of the question, that

\begin{align}
a_{11}^{-3} & = \frac{-1}{27} \\
a_{22}^{-3} & = 8 \\
a_{33}^{-3} & = -1 \\
\end{align}

Therefore 
\begin{align}
a_{11} & = -3 \\
a_{22} & = \frac{1}{2} \\
a_{33} & = -1 \\
\end{align}

and

$$A=\pmatrix{-3&0&0\cr0&\frac{1}{2}&0\cr0&0&-1}$$